# Объединение CSS файлов

Tags: css

проблема следующая: есть 2 файла **style.css** и **style-2.css**, писали 2 разных человека, при этом есть куски тупо повторяющиеся 1 в 1, как можно объединить с заменой повторяющихся строк чтобы на выходе получить 1 файл со всеми НЕ дублирующимися стилями? варианты типо @import или ctrl+c ctrl+v не предлагать

Comment: надавать им по рукам тапком.

Comment: Я думаю здесь можно попробовать минификатор какой-нибудь; например [этот](https://cssminifier.com) — по крайней мере если ввести два раза `.test{color: red;}`, то на выходе получается один `.test{color:red}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В npm есть [css-purge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-purge) предназначенный для удаления дубликатов css правил.

Есть [аддон для мозилы](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/), который смотрит используемые css правила на странице.

Можно попробовать использовать gulp. С помощью [gulp-concat-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css) объединить файлы css, далее с помощью [gulp-uncss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss) убрать неиспользуемые css правила.

Comment: вроде помогло, спасибо)